# Is it possible to boot a Full Installation of Fedora on a USB Drive with Ventoy/Multiboot Software?

Tags: fedora, boot, dual-boot, live-usb

I've been using Ventoy for booting live environments from ISO files.
I want to create a full installation of Fedora on a USB drive, not just a live USB.
To my situation: I have a friend's pc, my pc and a work pc on which I want to have the same data and programs etc. and thought the best way to do this would be a full install usb stick.
I understand that a full installation would allow me to save changes, install software, and update the system just like a regular installation, but on a portable USB stick. (correct?) And I'd like to use this full Fedora installation in a multiboot setup with Ventoy, alongside live Linux distributions and other ISO environments.

Is it possible to boot a full fedora/generally linux install (instead of a live usb with persistence which is something difference if i understood it correctly) with a multiboot setup like ventoy or would I have to setup something like grub?

Is what I'm doing even recommended?
Does this work if all CPU-architectures are the same? What if they aren't? Would a live boot with persistence work then? Are there any other problems I might want to pay attention to?

Thanks in advance for any advice or guidance you can offer!

Comment: I started booting ISO from grub before ventoy. So I am manually creating what ventoy does. I usually install Ubuntu, and have an ISO folder and boot many ISO from grub. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746692/fedora-live-usb-in-a-partition/746715?noredirect=1#comment1420632_746715 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot Fedora is using grub2, so same boot stanzas should work.