add partition and data onto usb stick already having bootable iso9660
I have a usb stick (actually a disk) and it is 5TB in size.
I do a cp rhel-8.10-x86_64-dvd.iso /dev/sde to it and it then works to boot from and install Redhat Linux.
What I would like to do is copy other various data into this disk but maintain the bootable rhel-8.10 install functionality.  Is this possible?
A lsblk after the copy of rhel iso to it shows
SIZE    FSTYPE     NAME
4.6T    iso9660    /dev/sde
13.3G   iso9660    /dev/sde1
 9.5M   vfat       /dev/sde2

is there a way to add an XFS partition such that it could be /dev/sde3 and mountable to make use of the remaining 4+ tb of space, while still maintaining the bootable functionality to install rhel?

I use Kubuntu and boot ISO directly from grub. So any drive over 32GB has a full  install and then various ISO & data. I used to use flash drives but they are relatively slow. Now have two external SSD with full installs, ISO & data. Highly recommend external SSD. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Multiboot_USB_drive & https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746692/fedora-live-usb-in-a-partition & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples Do not know specifics for Red Hat nor Fedora. I have an old Fedora Rawhide ISO boot entry, bit different parameters than my normal Kubuntu.

Another alternative. Most systems (except Windows) can just have ISO extracted into an ESP - efi system partition. It will be UEFI bootable only as no BIOS boot support. But then as standard FAT32 partition, you can add other partitions.

You can simply do that with fdisk, you just need to tell it to use the correct it partition table on the USB drive. Distribution ISO images are so called isohybrid images -- mix of iso9660 and multiple partition tables to make sure the system will boot everywhere. Simply use
sudo fdisk --type=dos --wipe=never /dev/sde

and add a new partition normally (use n and the answer the questions about partition type and size).
--type=dos will tell fdisk to use only the DOS partition table on the drive and --wipe=never will tell it to not wipe the iso9660 format when writing the changes.
Example of the result with CentOS ISO and a newly added partition formatted to ext4:
$ lsblk -f /dev/sdb
NAME   FSTYPE  FSVER            LABEL                         UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sdb    iso9660 Joliet Extension CentOS-Stream-9-BaseOS-x86_64 2024-05-27-03-57-45-00                              
├─sdb1 iso9660 Joliet Extension CentOS-Stream-9-BaseOS-x86_64 2024-05-27-03-57-45-00                              
├─sdb2 vfat    FAT12            ANACONDA                      4B96-9789                                           
└─sdb3 ext4    1.0                                            321c67bd-817e-4274-a4b1-01103c25a7b9


fdisk red text warns that my 5TB disk exceeds the 2TB msdos partition limit.  But I was able to get a /dev/sde3 from fdisk that was in iso9960 originally, but a mkfs.xfs /dev/sde3 fixed that.

if you know of a way to change the msdos partition table that came inherently from doing a cp rhel-8.10-x86_64-dvd.iso /dev/sde to GPT so i could get a sde that spans the entire 5TB of the drive, while still maintaining the bootable rhel8 install,  let me know
